# how i can go on particular activity after clicking on notification

Tags: java, android, android-activity, push-notification, onclick

i want my application should give me notification and on clicking on notification another activity should open  like whatsapp notifications
this is my code c an anyone help?????

```
 public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            //    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            //Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            //bundle.putString("msgBody",remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            //intent use for start this activity after click on notification
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Secondactivity.class);
            String valu=remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            intent.putExtra("notificationmessage",valu);
**strong text**            //here we are telling system after clicking you have to come on mainactivity
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            //here we are giving rights to main activity.FLAG_ONE_SHOT useful to indicate this pending intent can use only once
            PendingIntent pendingintent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            //notificationcompat useful for creating notification layout
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationbuilder=new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            notificationbuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            notificationbuilder.setContentTitle("FCM NOTIFICATION");
            notificationbuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            notificationbuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationbuilder.setContentIntent(pendingintent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0,notificationbuilder.build());

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an extra parameter in the message content for identifying the type. Then create notification manager with different activity based on that type value.

ex:

```
switch (type){
case 1:

 notification manager for activity A

break:

case 2:

 notification manager for activity B

break:

}
```